# i am getting this error: print("I am " + 187 + " years old") TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python-3.9

when i try run this:

```
User_Person = input("What is your name? ")

print("Hello " + User_Person + " i am 2xx-350")

User_Age = int(input("How old are you?"))

Robot_Age = 187

I_am_years_older = Robot_Age - User_Age

if User_Age == Robot_Age:
print("I am " + Robot_Age + " years old too")
else:
print("I am " + 187 + " years old")
print("That means i am " + I_am_years_older + " 
years older than you.")
```

I am a beginner so I may just be missing something obvious
Pls point out any solutions

Comment: Try using `str(187)` instead of just `187`. You can't simply join an `int` with `str`.

Comment: I tried doing this:  Robot_Age = str(187)  and it said: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Please share the code that you tried. Note that you have the same problem at the next line, where you try to concatenate a string with the integer `I_am_years_older`.

Comment: @eissamgaman You can't subtract an `int` from `str`. When you write like this `Robot_Age = str(187)`, then `Robot_Age` is an `string`. You are taking `User_Age` as `integer`. So you can't do this `I_am_years_older = Robot_Age - User_Age` subtraction. Keep `Robot_Age` as `Robot_Age = 187`. In `print("I am " + Robot_Age + " years old too")`, use `str(Robot_Age)` instead of just `Robot_Age`.

Comment: It's better to use python 3 f-string to avoid string concatenation headache: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings